# Can I install mac mini and wireless keyboard/mouse without USB keyboard/mouse?

Tags: keyboard, wifi, install, mouse

I want to buy mac mini.
But I do not want have USB keyboard/mouse, which will not be used after installing them because I will use wireless keyboard/mouse.
Can I install or reinstall mac os and install wireless keyboard/mouse without USB mouse/keyboard?

it is acceptable for me to have only a usb mouse because it is small.
if there are no ways to install os and wireless mouse/keyboard without USB mouse/keyboard,　are threre ways to install them with only a USB mouse?

Comment: You can use it with the wireless keyboard and mouse when it is installing

Comment: mac mini can be installed only with wireless mouse and keyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to buy a usb bluetooth, mac mini comes with no Bluetooth module installed! If your not it you have to buy the usb stick! Once this is done you can assign the keyboard and mouse to the mac mini! ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer. so if i get the usb bluetooth, i dont need both usb keyboard and usb mouse?

Comment: not. will connect the keyboard and mouse to the mac mini via usb! ;)

Comment: thank very much! now i can sell my windows pc and its mouse and keyboard.

Comment: The Mac Mini comes with no bluetooth module installed? Really? I've got a previous version rather than the current version and that certainly came with bluetooth as part of the standard build. It seems odd they would remove something like that.

Comment: [o rly](http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html)?

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong

Comment: On the Apple Specs page it clearly states "Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR"

Comment: Bluetooth has been standard since the last of the G4 Minis in late 2005:

 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini